# Genetic Algorithm to find angles for desired position in 4-axial manipulator using Denavit Hartenberg notation

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have an assignment to write a code in matlab to find angles for desired position of 4-axes industrial robot. 
So my idea at the beginning was to write function where you pass angles at joints, desired position and a result is distance between position of last joint and desired position.

At next step I made a loop which passes a lot of combinations and then we get a result where the distance is smallest. However this is highly inefficient, because code need about 18s to give the results (it iterates about 30k times).

But I've got a hint of using bulit in matlab genetic algorithm, but when I try to pass my funcion there i got  "Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."

And I wonder why, because when it iterates there is no such problem.
So in general I would like to use bulit in genetic algorithm in matlab to get this angles faster.

There are codes for my functions
Main funtion which I would like to use genetic algorythm (in Optimatization Tool)

I typed

- Fitness function: @genetiokos22
- No of variables: 4
- Linear inequalities: A = [eye(4);-eye(4)] ; B = [360,360,360,360,0,0,0,0]

  ```
  function result = genetikos22(th1,th2,th3,th4)

  %definied position to achive
  x0 = -997.7;
  y0 = 343.5;
  z0 = 1844.7;


  %constants
  d1 = 620;
  d2 = 0;
  d3 = 0;
  d4 = 0;
  d5 = 190;

  a1 = 220;
  a2 = 850;
  a3 = 850;
  a4 = 200;
  a5 = 0;

  al1 = 90;
  al2 = 0 ;
  al3 = 0;
  al4 = 90;
  al5 = 0;

  %variables theta

  th5 = 0;


  %obtainig position matrix with passj function

  J1 = passj(th1,d1,a1,al1);
  J2 = passj(th2,d2,a2,al2);
  J3 = passj(th3,d3,a3,al3);
  J4 = passj(th4,d4,a4,al4);
  J5 = passj(th5,d5,a5,al5);
  %Final J
  FJ = J1*J2*J3*J4*J5;
  x = FJ(1,4);
  y = FJ(2,4);
  z = FJ(3,4);



  result = dist3d(x,y,z,x0,y0,z0);


  end
  ```

Functions used inside

```
function J = passj(th,d,a,al)

TH=[cosd(th),-sind(th),0,0;sind(th),cosd(th),0,0;0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1];
D=[1,0,0,0;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,d;0,0,0,1];
A=[1,0,0,a;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,0;0,0,0,1];
AL=[1,0,0,0;0,cosd(al),-sind(al),0;0,sind(al),cosd(al),0;0,0,0,1];


J=TH*D*A*AL;
end

function result = dist3d(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2)

result = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2);
end
```

And now i show how it works in iteration model:
(where I use genettikos33 funtion, where I can pass also desired x,y,z position)

```
function result = iteracyjniever4(x0,y0,z0)

wyniki = zeros(23873,1);
tety = zeros(23873,4);
wyniki1 = zeros(512,1);
tety1 = zeros(512,4);
ii = 1;
ii1 = 1;



th1 = findth1(x0,y0);


    for th2 = -30:5:105
        for th3 = -235:5:-75
            for th4 = -120:5:15
                a = genetikos33(th1,th2,th3,th4,x0,y0,z0);
                wyniki(ii) = a ;
                tety(ii,:) = [th1 th2 th3 th4];
                ii = ii + 1;
            end
        end
    end

[min_dist, ixi] = min(wyniki);
tety(ixi,:);
wyniki(ixi);

th1 = tety(ixi,1);
th2 = tety(ixi,2) - 4;
th3 = tety(ixi,3) - 4;
th4 = tety(ixi,4) - 4;

th2max = tety(ixi,2) + 5;
th3max = tety(ixi,3) + 5;
th4max = tety(ixi,4) + 5;


while th2<th2max
    while th3<th3max
        while th4<th4max
            b = genetikos33(th1,th2,th3,th4,x0,y0,z0);
            wyniki1(ii1) = b ;
            tety1(ii1,:) = [th1 th2 th3 th4];
            ii1 = ii1 + 1;
            th4 = th4 + 1;
        end
        th4 = tety(ixi,4) - 19;
        th3 = th3 + 1;
    end
    th3 = tety(ixi,3) - 19;
    th2 = th2 + 1;
end


[min_dist1, ixi1] = min(wyniki1);
tety1(ixi1,:);
disp('distance to desired position')
wyniki1(ixi1)

result = tety1(ixi1,:);
```

And fuinctions used inside: